# AppEngine unit test non default queues in queue.yaml

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit, google-cloud-platform

We are in the process of migrating xml configuration files to yaml in a Java Appengine project.

All went well except unit tests, in fact we are using some unit tests to check some part of the code that uses non default queues, with the previous xml file we were doing something like this:

```
  private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
      new LocalServiceTestHelper(
          new LocalTaskQueueTestConfig()
              .setDisableAutoTaskExecution(false)
              .setCallbackClass(LocalTaskQueueTestConfig.DeferredTaskCallback.class)
              .setTaskExecutionLatch(latch)
              .setQueueXmlPath("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/queue.xml"));
```

But with the yaml file (queue.yaml), all the tests that uses this config fail and we couldn't find how to make the `LocalTaskQueueTestConfig` class to recognize that file.

Comment: In order to better understand your scenario. Are you testing in App Engine or locally ? also, how is your environment configured ? and lastly, why are you trying to do this ?  I’ll be looking forward to you response.

Comment: I'm testing locally and I'm using maven with Cloud SDK for that. I'm trying to do so because the standalone App Engine SDK is deprecated and I'm trying to migrate to Cloud SDK: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sdk-gcloud-migration

Comment: For the moment is not possible and the Official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/localunittesting) does not mentioned use of yaml all of the examples are using xml for that specific approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, but `LocalTaskQueueConfig#setQueueYamlPath(String)` is supported in [App Engine SDK 1.9.80](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/release-notes#April_20_2020).